# agregar horas con php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

que tal tengo dos campos que quiero agregar
que es uno de tiempo final el cual ya me agrega la diferencia
y otra que ya me da los minutos pero no se que formato debo agrgar

```
 $horaInicial="14:00:00";
 $minutoAnadir= new DateTime('00:15:00');
  
 $segundos_horaInicial=strtotime($horaInicial);
  
 $segundos_minutoAnadir=$minutoAnadir*60;
  
 $nuevaHora=date("H:i:s",$segundos_horaInicial+$segundos_minutoAnadir);
  
 echo "<br>".$nuevaHora;
```

lo que necesito es agregar dos campos de tipo minutos horas y segundos los cuales mandare por POST

erro
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: DateTime * int in C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\fechasdif.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\fechasdif.php on line 12

agrege el codigo como me dijo pero me parece que los cambios no se efectuan aqui muestro el ejemplo que se deberian agregar los datos sumar a la penalizacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por si acaso muestro mi codigo

```
if(isset($_POST['sw1']) == 2){ //si se ha presionado el boton "Actualizar" 

    $autonumero=!empty($_POST['autonumero']) ? $_POST['autonumero'] : NULL;
    $piloto_copiloto=!empty($_POST['piloto_copiloto']) ? $_POST['piloto_copiloto'] : NULL;
    $clase=!empty($_POST['clase']) ? $_POST['clase'] : NULL;
    $vuelta=!empty($_POST['vuelta']) ? $_POST['vuelta'] : NULL;
    $largada=!empty($_POST['largada']) ? $_POST['largada'] : NULL;
    $llegada=!empty ($_POST['llegada']) ? $_POST['llegada'] : NULL;
    $final=!empty($_POST['final']) ? $_POST['final'] : NULL;
    $tiempofinal=!empty($_POST['tiempofinal']) ? $_POST['tiempofinal'] : NULL;
    $penalizacion=!empty($_POST['penalizacion']) ? $_POST['penalizacion'] : NULL;
    $diferencia=!empty($_POST['diferencia']) ? $_POST['diferencia'] : NULL;
    
    $milesllegada=!empty($_POST['milesllegada']) ? $_POST['milesllegada'] : NULL;
    $centllegada=!empty($_POST['centllegada']) ? $_POST['centllegada'] : NULL;
    $milesfinal=!empty($_POST['milesfinal']) ? $_POST['milesfinal'] : NULL;
    $centfinal=!empty($_POST['centfinal']) ? $_POST['centfinal'] : NULL;
    
    $summiles=$milesllegada+$milesfinal;
    $sumcent=$centllegada+$centfinal;
    
    $fecha1 = new DateTime($llegada);//fecha inicial
    $fecha2 = new DateTime($final);//fecha de cierre
    $intervalo = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
    $interveniente=$intervalo->format('%H:%I');
    $fecha3 = new DateTime($penalizacion);//fecha inicial

    sscanf($fecha3, '%d:%d:%d', $h,$m,$s);
    $di = new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%dH%dM%dS', $h, $m, $s));
    
    $mHora=new DateTime($interveniente);
    $mHora->add($di);
    $sums=$mHora->format('H:i:s');

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Asuncion');
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');



$sql="INSERT INTO vuelta1 (autonumero, piloto_copiloto, clase, vuelta, largada, llegada,milesllegada,centllegada, final, milesfinal,centfinal,penalizacion, tiempofinal,milescomp,centcomomp,diferencia,actualizado_a) 
VALUES  ('$autonumero', '$piloto_copiloto', '$clase','$vuelta' ,'$largada','$llegada','$milesllegada','$centllegada', '$final', '$milesfinal','$centfinal','$penalizacion','$sums','$summiles','$sumcent','$diferencia','$now')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ //si la consulta se ejecuta con exito
        echo "La informacion se actualizo con exito"; //mensaje de exito
        header('Location: admin.php'); //redireccion a index.php
    }else{ //si ocurrio un error
        echo "Ocurrio un error al intentar actualizar"; //mensaje de error
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo en sí cuál es el problema. **Entendí que querías agregar un tiempo determinado a otro tiempo que ya existe**. ¿Podrías explicar al principio de la pregunta cuál es el problema y el contexto? Luego, si los datos, una vez habiendo probado que se producen correctamente, no se actualizan, sería por otro problema del código que no tendría nada que ver con el problema inicial planteado. Explica entonces cuál es el problema con las fechas: qué tienes, qué recibes y qué esperas obtener.

Comment: claro con el coddigo me aparece asi 
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct(): Argument #1 ($datetime) must be of type string, DateTime given in C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\upd1.php:103 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\upd1.php(103): DateTime->__construct(Object(DateTime)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\autos\upd1.php on line 103

Comment: ya lo resolvi muchas gracias agregp tu calificacion positiva

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

Si estás recibiendo algo así `00:05:00` con el tiempo a añadir (aquí se echa de menos un método createIntervalFromFormat), puedes crear un intervalo [con un truco explicado aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742351/5587982) (lo mejoramos, porque podemos prescindir de `list()`), usando [`sscanf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sscanf.php).

```
$horaInicial="14:00:00";
$toAdd="00:05:00";
#Asignamos variables para las posibles horas, minutos, segundos
#Podemos prescindir de list
sscanf($toAdd, '%d:%d:%d', $h,$m,$s);
#Creamos el DI con las variables
$di = new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%dH%dM%dS', $h, $m, $s));

$mHora=new DateTime($horaInicial);
$mHora->add($di);
echo $mHora->format('H:i:s');
```

**Salida:**

```
14:05:00
```

Como ves, la hora inicial se modificó en 5 minutos, según el valor que había en `$toAdd`.

---

No entiendo mucho lo que intentas hacer aquí:

```
$segundos_minutoAnadir=$minutoAnadir*60;
```

Sea como sea, tú podrías crear un objeto `DateTime` a partir de la hora inicial y modificarlo directamente con aquellos períodos que quieras agregar. En ese sentido, [el método `add()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php) te permite agregar al objeto cualquier intervalo de tiempo: años, meses, semanas, días, horas, minutos, segundos... Cada una tiene su inicial, como podrás ver en los ejemplos del Manual. Para los que no interesa aquí: Ponemos primero `PT` para indicar que es un período temporal (si no la `M` puede confundirse con meses), y luego pondremos el valor para los minutos seguido de `M` y el valor para los segundos seguido de `S` ([ver todas las especificaciones aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.construct.php)).

```
$horaInicial="14:00:00";
/*Minutos que se añadirán*/
$toAddM=15;
/*Segundos que se añadirán*/
$toAddS=2;
$mHora=new DateTime($horaInicial);
$mHora->add(new DateInterval("PT{$toAddM}M{$toAddS}S"));
echo $mHora->format('H:i:s');

#For test only
var_dump($mHora);
```

**Salida:**

```
14:15:02
```

Como ves, a la hora inicial se le añadieron 15 minutos y 2 segundos.

Este es el objeto completo:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-03-06 14:15:02.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

### Post-Data

Este código modifica el objeto original, si te interesa un objeto distinto, puedes clonar el original y modificar el nuevo, teniendo así dos objetos distintos.

Comment: Así masomenos pero lo que necesito es un formato el cual me permita agregar yo la hora y minuto que necesito por enwmplo

Comment: Ejemplo quiero agregar 00:05:00 dentro de la hora final

Comment: hola ya modifiue y agrege los valores que menciona ay deje como aparece